# External user logging into a server backed by Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD instance with a bunch of users, these users have accounts of the form *@*.onmicrosoft.com

I have an Azure VM which is backed by this Azure AD instance, I am able to log into the machine using the above accounts, the issue lies in the case where I am adding an external user to the Azure AD.

I have added an account of the form: test@outlook.com as an external user to my Azure AD.
[image]

(Where the red bars are the start of the email address, so "test" in this case).

I am then attempting to log into my VM with this outlook account however I keep getting an invalid username/password dialog.

If I open up "Computer Management" and do a search through all users I see the user there:

Any ideas on how I can use this user account to log into the VM backed by Azure AD?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD domain service?

Comment: Ensure that the UPN of the user has been configured in Azure AD to sign in.More about credentials-related issues for joining Windows VM to Azure AD DS , refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal#troubleshooting-domain-join

Comment: I believe we are using Azure AD domain services.
For an outlook.com account that has been added to an contoso.onmicrosoft.com Azure tenant,  how would I go about adding the UPN? That document isnt really clear.

Comment: Have you referred to  these steps in this document to configure your  AD DS?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started

Comment: Those documents seem to just refer to a domain that has been created.  
I can login using: blake@contoso.onmicrosoft.com to the VM.
I have added the *@outlook.com, the *@outlook.com has been added to the Azure AD however I still can't log into the VM using the *@outlook.com